# Weird pointer issue...constructing BST using array of pointers

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, binary-search-tree

So I am trying to create a BST using an array of pointers. My algorithm is correct (tested a version that doesn't use pointers), but when using the below code, the following occurs:

1. If I add the first element, it is added to position 1 of the array.
2. If I add a second element, for some reason, position 1 of the array is overwritten to this element, and then the program continues (else part) and attempts to insert it again.

EG. (traced the program with a bunch of couts)

```
1. Call add(5, 1)
inserting 5 into position 1
position 1 is now 5

2. Call add(4, 1)
position 1 is now 4
moving right
inserting 4 into position 3
position 1 is now 4
```

...

```
template <typename Item> void ABTree<Item>::add(Item input, int index){
    if (array[1]==0){
        array[1] = &input;
        size++;
    }else{
        if (input < *array[index]){
            if (array[2*index] == 0){
                array[2*index] = &input;
                size++;
            }else
                add(input, 2*index);
        }else{
            if (array[(2*index)+1] == 0){
                array[(2*index)+1] = &input;
                size++;
            }else
                add(input, (2*index)+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: "if( array[0] == 0 )"

Comment: I want array[1] to be the root of the BST, therefore am always calling add with the index of 1.

Comment: Is Item a type of pointer?

Comment: Taking the address of a parameter is like throwing up a big blinking sign that says "Welcome, trouble!".

Comment: I am passing an Item (in this case an int) into add. The array is of Items, eg. Item * array[40];

Comment: If you've changed `input` to be passed by reference or pointer (and dynamically allocating memory for it, e.g. using `new` or smart pointers) and it's still giving a problem, please provide an [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example)](http://sscce.org) (with the emphasis on self-contained).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I altered the code to accept a pointer to the item to be inserted instead.

```
if (array[1]==0){
    array[1] = input;
    size++;
}else{
    if (*input < *array[index]){
        if (array[2*index] == 0){
            array[2*index] = input;
            size++;
        }else
            add(input, 2*index);
    }else{
        if (array[(2*index)+1] == 0){
            array[(2*index)+1] = input;
            size++;
        }else
            add(input, (2*index)+1);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole lotta troubles in the code you've provided.

1. Assigning address of the temporary variable is
   inadmissible. The "input" variable ends up right after the add
   function returns. Storing its address than is meaningless  and leads
   to almost inevitable crash. In particular, when you're adding second element to your array, those condition checks:

   - if (array[1]==0)
   - if (input < *array[index])

   yields undefined result, and therefore undefined control flow.
2. I don't know type of the container you're using but I assume it to
   be a kind of vector or even plain C array. If my guess is true, you
   should perform a bounds check before accessing array's elements with
   the index.
3. No reallocation of the memory accupied by the array is performed.
   Or, alternatively, if you're using a constant size array, no check
   is performed (see 2).

So, basing on the output, you've got the following sequence when adding second element:

- On the check that head is empty - false;
- On the check if (input < *array[index]) - false, since array[index] contains garbage, this is why "inserting 4 into position 3" despite we should add 4 to the position 2;
- On the check if (array[(2*index)+1] == 0) - again false, since this element contains garbage too (am I right that you didn't initialize your array with zeros?);
- So, recursive call to the add routine happens...

Comment: I don't believe `if (array[1]==0)` will cause undefined behaviour. The memory at the address may no longer be accessible, but that doesn't mean that a variable storing the address itself isn't accessible, or that the value it has changed because the memory is no longer accessible.

Comment: Kind of. On the second insertion, the head is overwritten to the new value to be inserted, so then when the check 'if (input < *array[index])' is performed, it returns false, therefore inserting at pos 3.